# Multiline edit not working (jupyter lab)?

Tags: settings, jupyter-lab

After upgrading to Jupyter lab 3 through pip, I cannot select multiple lines by alt + mousedrag as I used to (Mac).

The cursor changes shape, but I'm unable to select any text. The issue is present in Safari and Firefox

I have not seen anyone else report this issue, and I'm speculating if it's on my part.

I hope that someone can help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + **mouse click**.

For me it worked, Im using Firefox web Browser